# Getting random row through SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, database, random, sqlalchemy

How do I select one or more random rows from a table using SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

This is very much a database-specific issue.

I know that PostgreSQL, SQLite, MySQL, and Oracle have the ability to order by a random function, so you can use this in SQLAlchemy:

```
from  sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func, select

select.order_by(func.random()) # for PostgreSQL, SQLite

select.order_by(func.rand()) # for MySQL

select.order_by('dbms_random.value') # For Oracle
```

Next, you need to limit the query by the number of records you need (for example using `.limit()`).

Bear in mind that at least in PostgreSQL, selecting random record has severe perfomance issues; [here](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2007/09/16/my-thoughts-on-getting-random-row/) is good article about it.

Comment: +1. Same as Postgres works for SQLite:  `select.order_by(func.random()).limit(n)`

Comment: You can use order_by('dbms_random.value') in Oracle.

Comment: I've added the import as best as I can tell without SQLAlchemy installed - can someone confirm it's right..? Also edited bernie and Buttons840 suggestions into the answer

Comment: If you are using declarative models: `session.query(MyModel).order_by(func.rand()).first`

Comment: Thanks @trinth, it worked when I added paranthesis to the end: `session.query(MyModel).order_by(func.rand()).first()`

Comment: Why `.rand` and `.random`? Shouldn't SQLAlchemy take care of such DB-specific idiosyncrasies for us?

Comment: Since SQLAlchemy v0.4, `func.random()` is a generic function that compiles to the database's random implementation.

Comment: appears that func.random() does not work with oracle. suggest using `select.order_by(sqlalchemy.literal_column('dbms_random.value'))` to avoid warnings

Answer (score 31):

Here's four different variations, ordered from slowest to fastest. `timeit` results at the bottom:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from sqlalchemy.orm import load_only

def simple_random():
    return random.choice(model_name.query.all())

def load_only_random():
    return random.choice(model_name.query.options(load_only('id')).all())

def order_by_random():
    return model_name.query.order_by(func.random()).first()

def optimized_random():
    return model_name.query.options(load_only('id')).offset(
            func.floor(
                func.random() *
                db.session.query(func.count(model_name.id))
            )
        ).limit(1).all()
```

`timeit` results for 10,000 runs on my Macbook against a PostgreSQL table with 300 rows:

```
simple_random(): 
    90.09954111799925
load_only_random():
    65.94714171699889
order_by_random():
    23.17819356000109
optimized_random():
    19.87806927999918
```

You can easily see that using `func.random()` is far faster than returning all results to Python's `random.choice()`.

Additionally, as the size of the table increases, the performance of `order_by_random()` will degrade significantly because an `ORDER BY` requires a full table scan versus the `COUNT` in `optimized_random()` can use an index.

Comment: What about picking samples? Like what  `random.sample()` do? What is optimized way here?

Comment: Open a new question and link to it and I'll take a stab at answering. If possible, specify the underlying flavor of SQL as that influences the answer as well.

Comment: Isn't this using `flask-sqlalchemy`?

Answer (score 27):

If you are using the orm and the table is not big (or you have its amount of rows cached) and you want it to be database independent the really simple approach is.

```
import random
rand = random.randrange(0, session.query(Table).count()) 
row = session.query(Table)[rand]
```

This is cheating slightly but thats why you use an orm.

Comment: rand = random.randrange(0, session.query(Table).count())

Comment: You choose and create all objects before choose one of

Comment: How about `random.choice(session.query(Table))`?

Answer (score 23):

There is a simple way to pull a random row that IS database independent.
Just use .offset() . No need to pull all rows:

```python
import random
query = DBSession.query(Table)
rowCount = int(query.count())
randomRow = query.offset(int(rowCount*random.random())).first()
```

Where Table is your table (or you could put any query there).
If you want a few rows, then you can just run this multiple times, and make sure that each row is not identical to the previous.

Comment: Update - at around 10 million rows in mysql this actually started to get a little slow I guess you could optimize it.

Comment: Works well for me in a ~500k rows setting.

Comment: Now up at 11 million rows on Oracle.... not so good anymore :-) Linear degradation, but still... I have to find something else.

Comment: @Mario Share when you do :)

Comment: I haven't done any workbench tests, but I changed the query to this: query.offset(random.randint(0, rowCount - 1)).limit(1).first() and it's working fine. But my database is pretty small compared to yours.

Comment: @Jayme: you could use `query.offset(random.randrange(rowCount)).limit(1).first()`.

Comment: @Jayme also, is there a reason to use `.limit(1)` before `.first()`? It seems redundant. Perhaps, `query.offset(random.randrange(row_count)).first()` is enough.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I don't remember whether the sql generate was better, or I used it just to not have to handle the IndexError exception in case of no results. Because of accessing "query[0]".
But the docs say that first already applies the limit of one.
Seems you are right again ;)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian found it here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.first
I guess the limit was kept because of another piece of code I used to get pages of random items and reduced it to get just one. Well, anyway thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Some SQL DBMS, namely Microsoft SQL Server, DB2, and [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) have implemented the SQL:2003 `TABLESAMPLE` clause. Support was added to SQLAlchemy [in version 1.1](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3718). It allows returning a sample of a table using different sampling methods – the standard requires `SYSTEM` and `BERNOULLI`, which return a desired approximate percentage of a table.

In SQLAlchemy [`FromClause.tablesample()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.FromClause.tablesample) and [`tablesample()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.tablesample) are used to produce a [`TableSample`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TableSample) construct:

```
# Approx. 1%, using SYSTEM method
sample1 = mytable.tablesample(1)

# Approx. 1%, using BERNOULLI method
sample2 = mytable.tablesample(func.bernoulli(1))
```

There's a slight gotcha when used with mapped classes: the produced `TableSample` object must be aliased in order to be used to query model objects:

```
sample = aliased(MyModel, tablesample(MyModel, 1))
res = session.query(sample).all()
```

---

Since many of the answers contain performance benchmarks, I'll include some simple tests here as well. Using a simple table in PostgreSQL with about a  million rows and a single integer column, select (approx.) 1% sample:

```
In [24]: %%timeit
    ...: foo.select().\
    ...:     order_by(func.random()).\
    ...:     limit(select([func.round(func.count() * 0.01)]).
    ...:           select_from(foo).
    ...:           as_scalar()).\
    ...:     execute().\
    ...:     fetchall()
    ...: 
307 ms ± 5.72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [25]: %timeit foo.tablesample(1).select().execute().fetchall()
6.36 ms ± 188 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [26]: %timeit foo.tablesample(func.bernoulli(1)).select().execute().fetchall()
19.8 ms ± 381 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Before rushing to use `SYSTEM` sampling method one should know that it samples *pages*, not individual tuples, so it might not be suitable for small tables, for example, and may not produce as random results, if the table is clustered.

---

If using a dialect that does not allow passing the sample percentage / number of rows and seed as parameters, and a driver that does not inline values, then either pass the values as literal SQL text *if they are static*, or inline them using a custom SQLA compiler extension:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql import TableSample

@compiles(TableSample)
def visit_tablesample(tablesample, self, asfrom=False, **kw):
    """ Compile `TableSample` with values inlined.
    """
    kw_literal_binds = {**kw, "literal_binds": True}
    text = "%s TABLESAMPLE %s" % (
        self.visit_alias(tablesample, asfrom=True, **kw),
        tablesample._get_method()._compiler_dispatch(self, **kw_literal_binds),
    )

    if tablesample.seed is not None:
        text += " REPEATABLE (%s)" % (
            tablesample.seed._compiler_dispatch(self, **kw_literal_binds)
        )

    return text

from sqlalchemy import table, literal, text

# Static percentage
print(table("tbl").tablesample(text("5 PERCENT")))
# Compiler inlined values
print(table("tbl").tablesample(5, seed=literal(42)))
```

Comment: Has anyone been able to implement this with an Azure SQL db? I'm tring but i get ```
ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Variables are not allowed in the TABLESAMPLE or REPEATABLE clauses. (497) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting edge case that the implementation does not cover; by the looks of it passing the percentage or seed as a parameter is not supported. The Azure dialect would need to inline the argument in the query compiler. I can produce an example of that later today.

Comment: @robertfranklin I hope the additions help in getting it to work.

Answer (score 2):

**This is my function to select random row(s) of a table:**

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func

def random_find_rows(sample_num):
    if not sample_num:
        return []

    session = DBSession()
    return session.query(Table).order_by(func.random()).limit(sample_num).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I use:

```
from random import randint

rows_query = session.query(Table)                # get all rows
if rows_query.count() > 0:                       # make sure there's at least 1 row
    rand_index = randint(0,rows_query.count()-1) # get random index to rows 
    rand_row   = rows_query.all()[rand_index]    # use random index to get random row
```

Comment: This would be incredibly slow on big tables. You would be grabbing every single row and then slicing it up.

Comment: Wow yeah, this is not great. If there is a query to get table record count, that would be a better approach. This was done on a web-app with a small DB, no longer working with that company, so I can't do much about it.

Answer (score -3):

### this solution will select a single random row

This solution requires that the primary key is named id, it should be if its not already:

```
import random
max_model_id = YourModel.query.order_by(YourModel.id.desc())[0].id
random_id = random.randrange(0,max_model_id)
random_row = YourModel.query.get(random_id)
print random_row
```

Comment: This fails when you have a gap in your id's.

Answer (score -8):

Theres a couple of ways through SQL, depending on which data base is being used.

(I think SQLAlchemy can use all these anyways)

mysql:

```
SELECT colum FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1
```

MSSQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 column FROM table
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

IBM DB2:

```
SELECT column, RAND() as IDX
FROM table
ORDER BY IDX FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Oracle:

```
SELECT column FROM
(SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
WHERE rownum = 1
```

However I don't know of any standard way

Comment: Yeah. I know how to do it in SQL (I posted that answer in http://beta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql#19568) but was searching for a SQLAlchemy specific solution.