# Delete rows from Query Object

Tags: sqlalchemy

I was wondering if it's possible to delete some random rows from a Query Object before doing a bulk update.

**Example:**

```
writerRes = self.session.query(table)
writerRes = writerRes.filter(table.userID==3)
-> Delete some of the rows randomly
writerRes.update({"userID": 4})
```

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

[Selecting random row with SA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60805/getting-random-row-through-sqlalchemy) depends on the database.  Based on that answer.

Postgresql and Sqlite3:

```
number_of_random_rows = 3
rand_rows = session.query(table.userid).order_by(func.random()).limit(number_of_random_rows).subquery()
session.query(table).filter(table.userid.in_(rand_rows)).delete(synchronize_session='fetch')
```

MySQL:

```
number_of_random_rows = 3
rand_rows = session.query(table.userid).order_by(func.rand()).limit(number_of_random_rows).subquery()
session.query(table).filter(table.userid.in_(rand_rows)).delete(synchronize_session='fetch')
```

...

Comment: I made a mistake ... The code looks great but it doesn't work for me. I get this error `OperationalError: (OperationalError) only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression`. Any Idea?

Comment: What database are you using and what code are you running?  I only tested it on SQLite & Postgres.

Comment: I'm using the SQLite Database and I'm running the code you posted except that I filter the rows before running your code: writerRes = writerRes.filter(table.userID==4)