# How do you determine sqlalchemy driver from the session?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Some libraries and sites (like [kotti](http://kotti.pylonsproject.org/)) expose a database session that is loaded from a configuration file (it uses pyramid).

In general you can ignore the driver for sqlalchemy, but there are a few issues like [getting a random row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60805/getting-random-row-through-sqlalchemy) and [using timezones with sqlite](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#typedecorator-recipes), which require you to have specific behavior for different engines.

Thing is, I can't see to find out how to determine what driver you're using at run time.

How do you do this?

Specifically, how, from a session (not an engine or a session factory) can you work backwards and figure this out?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you do this

```
session.bind.dialect.name
```

it will return something like `sqlite` or `mysql`, i.e. the part at the beginning of a URL (`mysql://...`). Most other information can also be fetched from the [`dialect`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/internals.html#sqlalchemy.engine.interfaces.Dialect) object if you are interested in more. You can find this on any `engine` or `connection` (which `bind` is).