# How to reproducibly query random rows with SQLAlchemy from PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, random, sqlalchemy

I am trying to pseudo-randomly select rows from a PostgreSQL table using SQLAlchemy, but I need to use a `seed` to guarantee reproducibility of the query. The specific case is concerning a publication being submitted, tied to a codebase.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60815/3923962) does a great job introducing how one can leverage the following one-liner to select *a single random row*:

```
select.order_by(func.random()) # for PostgreSQL, SQLite
```

Further, one can select **many** of psuedo-random rows via:

```
select.order_by(func.random()).limit(n)
```

But how do I ensure that I select the same psuedo-random rows every time I run the above query?

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the `setseed(n)` postgreSQL method. Using `sqlalchemy` and [ChEMBL](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/) as our sample DB, the full solution looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func, select

query = select([MoleculeRecord.molregno]).order_by(func.random()).limit(500)
SEED = .5  # Change this to any float from -1.0 -> 1.0 to get different query results

e = create_engine("postgres:///chembl_25")
conn = e.connect()
conn.execute(f"SELECT setseed({SEED})")

firstQueryResults = [x.molregno for x in conn.execute(query)]
secondQueryResults = [x.molregno for x in conn.execute(query)]

assert(firstQueryResults == secondQueryResults)
```

This returns 500 random rows, with the invariant that **these 500 rows will always be the same** each time this query is executed. Too select different random rows, change the `SEED` variable too something different, between -1.0 and 1.0.

Comment: As a note for Postgresql, the `TABLESAMPLE` clause also supports using a seed for repeatable results.

Comment: I had to enclose the query in a call to text(), as in:
```
conn.execute(text(f"SELECT setseed({SEED})"))
```